# Correlation between two matrices with different amount of columns in R

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to find the correlation between the two datasets that contain a different number of columns/features, I looked into the Canonical correlation but it gives corr between each feature, but I want find the correlation between the two datasets. So I want to just have one number at the end. I wonder what are some ways I can do this? Lets say my dataset A contains 5 tickers of stock daily price for 3 years, and dataset B contains 10 stocks daily price for 3 years. How can I find the correlation between A and B?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do:

```
A = matrix(rnorm(260*5, sd=0.02), ncol=5)
colnames(A) <- paste0('a', 1:5)

B = matrix(rnorm(260*3, sd=0.02), ncol=3)
colnames(B) <- paste0('b', 1:3)

cor(x=A, y=B)
```